# Android - Automate HTML Checkbox and Submit

Tags: android, html, checkbox, submit

I want my app to automatically access a webpage, check or uncheck a box and click submit

I have tried many codes given here with no success.

eg:

### html snippet:

```
<tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="Yes"        ></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
                <p>　</td>
                <td width="112" height="27" align="right">
                <input type="submit" value="SubmitForm" style="float: left"></td>
```

---

I want my code to toggle the "yes" and then click the submit button "SubmitForm"

thanks!

Comment: I don't know many of the specifics involved with what you are trying to do. However from what you've posted here it appears as though you are trying to automatically bypass something that it was intended the user manually do. If that is the case I think you'll find it to be rather difficult if not impossible.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am making an easier interface on android to control the webpage. which I was able to do nicely on visual basic

Comment: Did you create the web page too?

Comment: Sounds like hes making some spambot or survey thing... Either way, if its a checkbox, its not going to work.

Comment: You can say I made the web page. Actually, I own the server and the webpage which is stored on it (currently I am using stock webpage, but I can modify it), thanks

Answer (score 0):

usually something like this http://kspace.in/blog/2008/05/30/submit-html-form-using-java/

```
package post;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class HttpPostForm
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      URL url = new URL( "http://www.aaaa.com/xyz.asp" );

      HttpURLConnection hConnection = (HttpURLConnection)
                             url.openConnection();
      HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects( true );

      hConnection.setDoOutput( true );
      hConnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 

      PrintStream ps = new PrintStream( hConnection.getOutputStream() );
      ps.print("param1=abcd&param2=10341");
      ps.close();

      hConnection.connect();

      if( HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK == hConnection.getResponseCode() )
      {
        InputStream is = hConnection.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("output.html");
        int data;
        while((data=is.read()) != -1)
        {
          os.write(data);
        }
        is.close();
        os.close();
        hConnection.disconnect();
      }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: works for me , anyway I have posted the content of the webpage